# Why does this selenium not click "next page" until end?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I am writing a scraping code for the website Upwork, and need to click through each page for job listings. Here is my python code, which I used selenium to web crawl.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from os.path  import basename
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.upwork.com/o/jobs/browse/c/design-creative/")


link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
while EC.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Next")):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.linkText, "Next")))
    link.click()
```

Comment: You need to give more details. When does it stop working? what happens when it stop?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems:

1. `EC` has no attribute `elementToBeClickable`. In `Python` you should use `element_to_be_clickable`
2. Your `link` defined on the first page only, so using it on the second page should give you `StaleElementReferenceException`
3. There is no `wait` variable defined in your code. I guess you mean something like

   ```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   ```
4. `By` has no attribute `linkText`. Try `LINK_TEXT` instead

Try to use below code to get required behavior

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
while True:
    try:
        wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, Next"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

This should allow you to click `Next` button while it's available